# devise trackable migration error using mysql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

as I was following a tutorial I came across an error while doing the migration which I couldn't figure out.
an error occurred while migrating the code which I wrote for the trackable devise.
it'd be helpful if you can give an answer in form of code with an explaination since I'm a beginner
thank you.

**trackable**

```
class AddTrackableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    unless column_exists?(:users, :sign_in_count)
      add_column :users, :sign_in_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false 
    end
    unless column_exists?(:users, :current_sign_in_at)
      add_column :users, :current_sign_in_at, :datetime
    end
    unless column_exists?(:users, :last_sign_in_at)
      add_column :users, :last_sign_in_at, :datetime
    end
    unless column_exists?(:users, :current_sign_in_ip)
      add_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :inet
    end
    unless column_exists?(:users, :last_sign_in_ip)
      add_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :inet  
    end
  end
 
  def down
    remove_columns :users, :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip
  end
end
```

**error**

```
== 20210817054855 AddTrackableToDevise: migrating =============================
-- column_exists?(:users, :sign_in_count)
   -> 0.0029s
-- column_exists?(:users, :current_sign_in_at)
   -> 0.0023s
-- column_exists?(:users, :last_sign_in_at)
   -> 0.0020s
-- column_exists?(:users, :current_sign_in_ip)
   -> 0.0020s
-- add_column(:users, :current_sign_in_ip, :inet)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
 
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inet' at line 1
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/db/migrate/20210817054855_add_trackable_to_devise.rb:13:in `up'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
 
Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inet' at line 1
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/db/migrate/20210817054855_add_trackable_to_devise.rb:13:in `up'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
 
Caused by:
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inet' at line 1
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/db/migrate/20210817054855_add_trackable_to_devise.rb:13:in `up'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/user/ruby_projects/ruby_auth/authapp/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all occurrences of `inet` in your migration to `:string` and it should work fine.